# CorelDraw does not preserve pattern fill when exporting to SVG

Tags: svg, coreldraw

I have a big vector picture in CorelDraw X7. I made a small square bitmap texture and converted it to fill pattern and then filled a large figure with it. I expect that when I export to SVG the bitmap ends up filled as the SVG pattern tag but instead it is copied many times to fit. It looks fine but the problem is its large size over 1MB due to the texture being copied many times. How do I fill and export to SVG a bitmap texture making it size-efficient?

Comment: Have you cross checked if the pattern is really a bitmap?

Comment: To make it size efficient, make the pattern another vector, which could reduce the size.